# matching underscore character in sqldf r

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a data frame df,

```
df = data.frame(name=c("jean", "lucie", "marie", "alain", "dupont", "stephane"),
  address=c("A3_Lyon" ,"paris_A1", "Paris_A2_Test", "Par1", "Paris_A2de2_Lyon",   'Lille_Aide_'))
```

I want to choose the address which contains *A2*, how i can do that with `sqldf`? This instruction give me wrong results:

```
sqldf("select * from df where address like '%_A2_%'")
##     name          address
## 1  marie    Paris_A2_Test
## 2 dupont Paris_A2de2_Lyon
```

The correct answer for me is:

```
##     name          address
## 1  marie    Paris_A2_Test
```

How can I do that

Comment: Can't you just do `df[grepl("_A2_", df$address), ]`? or if you like the "like" syntax, maybe `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[address %like% "_A2_"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The _ matches any given single character within a LIKE statement for most SQL dialects.  Using the default SQL driver for sqldf (SQLite) you can replace the like statement with `glob` which uses * and ? instead of % and _ respectively or attempt to specify an escape:

```
 sqldf("select * from df where address glob '*_A2_*'")

 sqldf("select * from df where address like '%\\_A2\\_%' ESCAPE '\\'")
```